# Sending Android market public key across the internet

Tags: android

Is it safe to send the Android Market public key in raw base64 form across the internet?  What problems could I encounter if I did this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where on the internet are you sending it, and why are you sending it? It should be okay if the target is expecting a base 64 encoded public key.

As for threat there isn't much of one. Anyone can see your public key. That's the point of public keys, share them with anyone you want to be able to decrypt anything signed with your private key. It's your private key that could cause problems if someone got a hold of it.

Anyone who loads your app will need your public key to decrypt the hash signature to make sure the app is really yours. You use your private key to sign the app, and the public is used to decrypt the signed hash (a hash is a number calculated from the file, if the file changes even a little bit the hash should change dramatically, so you know it hasn't been tampered with), and make sure it's yours. If it was signed by someone else's key then it can't be decrypted with your public key. Since it does decrypt the hash the user knows it's your app. Your public is actually embedded in the certificate for your app.

Also this is why your private key needs to be secure, if someone got a hold of your private key then they can impersonate your signature.

Comment: I will send the public key to clients that need to download licenses, I will not embed it in the application like the android library does in their example applications.

Comment: And the public key is used to make sure the licenses are authentic? Should be fine.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to do differently, but an android phone won't install an app without a conventionally formatted signature.

Comment: @Chris this is an Android Market key, `not` an application public key.

Comment: Certificates are generally application-specific unless a developer chooses to use the same one for multiple apps so they can have a shared user id.  Perhaps you should explain what you are actually trying to accomplish by sending a key across the internet outside of the market's inclusion of the certificate in the download.